# call ds_list from diffrent object error

Tags: game-maker, gml

I have created a textbox object and in its create event it creates list like

```
lines = ds_list_create();
```

in step event of textbox I use `ds_list_add(lines, "line one");`
and it works fine.

Now I have a diffrent object that try to call `ds_list_add(Textbox.lines, "line from diff object");`

but on running it gives error about var not set before reading. i tried also to change to `global.list = ds_list_create();` and still same problems.

can someone explain how to call `ds_list` from diffrent object.

Comment: Is textbox object created before second object where you tried add new lines? (room settings - instance order). And how many instances of textbox you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ds_list_*` functions right like you did. Just, you must make sure the data structures a function is referring to does actually exists.

I tried the following for testing purposes. Create two objects, `objTextBox` and `objOther` and set their events as follows.

For object `objTextbox`:

> *Create* Event
>   `list = ds_list_create();`
>
> *Press 'Space'* Event
>   `var str = get_string("I'm objTextbox:","");`
>   `ds_list_add(list,str);`
>
> *Draw* Event
>   `for (var i=0;i<ds_list_size(list);i++)`
>   `draw_text(10,10+15*i,string(ds_list_find_value(list,i)));`

For object objOther:

> *Press 'Shift'* Event:
>   `var str = get_string("I'm objOther:","");`
>   `ds_list_add(objTextbox.list,str);`

Now add them to a room, and make sure first object to be created is `objTextbox`, which is the one creating the `ds_list`. Run.

When dealing with data structures, always make sure they were created before working with them.